# apt-get update throws error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, xubuntu, ppa

I get the following error when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/opencv2.3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/opencv2.3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gijzelaar_opencv2.3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gijzelaar_opencv2.3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gijzelaar_opencv2.3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gijzelaar_opencv2.3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

How can I solve this? My ubuntu version is 16.04

Comment: You should know that PPAs may not have files for your Ubuntu version after some time. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I had a look in http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/opencv2.3/ubuntu/dists/  (one of the PPAs you'd added) and the only supported releases were 11.04 & 11.10.  If you add PPAs, only add ones that provide support for 16.04 (Xenial)  or whatever version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 2):

The `ppa:gijzelaar/opencv2.3` does not have packages for 16.04 LTS (xenial).

The solution is to remove problematic PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gijzelaar/opencv2.3
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_gijzelaar_opencv2.3*
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` and so on.